# ReheapUp and ReheapDown Recursive to Iterative Conversion C#

Tags: c#, recursion, heap, binary-tree, iteration

I've been asked to convert recursive ReheapUp and ReheapDown algorithms to an alternative iterative form. Here is the psuedocode for the recursive versions:

```
ReheapUp(node)
begin
   if NOT node = 0
       parent ← (node - 1) / 2 // integer division
       if heap[node] > heap[parent]
           Swap(heap[parent], heap[node])
           ReheapUp(parent)
       end-if
   end-if
end

ReheapDown(node)
begin
   leftChild ← node * 2 + 1
   rightChild ← node * 2 + 2
   if leftChild <= lastUsed
       largest ← leftChild
       if rightChild <= lastUsed AND array[largest] < array[rightChild]
           largest ← rightChild
       end-if
       if array[node] < array[largest]
           Swap(array[node], array[largest])
           ReheapDown(largest)
       end-if
   end-if
end
```

Here are my attempts:

```
private void ReheapUp(int index)
{
   bool Terminate;
   int Processing = index;

   do
   {
       Terminate = true;

       if (Processing != 0)
       {
           int Parent = PARENT(Processing);

           if (_Data[Processing].CompareTo(_Data[Parent]) > 0)
           {
               Utility.Swap(ref _Data[Parent], ref _Data[Processing]);
               Terminate = false;
               Processing = Parent;
           }
       }
   } while (!Terminate);
}

private void ReheapDown(int index)
{
   bool Terminate;

   int Processing = index,
       Largest = -1;

   do
   {
       Terminate = true;
       int LeftChild = CLEFT(Processing),
           RightChild = CRIGHT(Processing);

       if (LeftChild <= _LastUsed)
       {
           Largest = LeftChild;

           if (RightChild <= _LastUsed && _Data[Largest].CompareTo(_Data[RightChild]) < 0)
               Largest = RightChild;

           if (_Data[index].CompareTo(_Data[Largest]) < 0)
           {
               Utility.Swap(ref _Data[Processing], ref _Data[Largest]);
               Terminate = false;
               Processing = Largest;
           }
       }
   } while (!Terminate);
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please tell me what you think is wrong.

Comment: @paqogomez The iterative code that I've written isn't correct. When sample data is entered the result isn't reheaped correctly.

Comment: Please add sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Came across this while googling and I'm curious, where did `Lastused` come from in your pseudocode? I see it neither declared or set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ReheapDown method has a small issue.
This should work:

```
    private void ReheapDown(int index)
    {
        bool Terminate;

        int Processing = index,
            Largest = -1;

        do
        {
            Terminate = true;
            int LeftChild = CLEFT(Processing),
                RightChild = CRIGHT(Processing);

            if (LeftChild <= _LastUsed)
            {
                Largest = LeftChild;

                if (RightChild <= _LastUsed && _Data[Largest].CompareTo(_Data[RightChild]) < 0)
                    Largest = RightChild;

                if (_Data[Processing].CompareTo(_Data[Largest]) < 0)
                {
                    Utility.Swap(ref _Data[Processing], ref _Data[Largest]);
                    Terminate = false;
                    Processing = Largest;
                }
            }
        } while (!Terminate);
    }
```